# How can I remove an incompatible package?

Tags: package

I recently checked my package menu, and found a large number of packages labelled `incompat`. I can't delete them by typing `d` on the package menu or running `M-x package-menu-mark-delete`. Are these packages installed but ignored? If they are present on my system, how do I go about deleting them?

Comment: I recommend reading the Emacs Manual node on [Packages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html). It's not too long and it should answer most parts of your question (not sure if it describes `incompat` packages).

Comment: @Basil: I've read the manual, it does not describe `incompat` packages, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure they are installed?

The difference between them and the obsolete packages in my package list is that the obsolete packages have a relative path listed in the `Status:` line, just like installed packages or dependency packages.

I think the package manager lists them as `incompatible` to show that they're not installable. I also cannot mark not installed packages for deletion, as I can't with the single package which is listed as `incompatible`.

If I get package.el correctly, a incompatible package may require a newer emacs, or in the lonely case of `kiwix` in my current Emacs installation because it depends on a package which isn't available.

Comment: Currently, on my system, most incompatible packages are old and abandoned ones that depend on packages that have since changed name. For example, "nrepl" appears to have become "clojure-repl" but currently listed "nrepl-ritz", "slough" and "nrepl-decompile" depend on "nrepl".